# IBM Watson speech-to-text addon for Twilio affect one phone number

Tags: twilio, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

Using the IBM Watson Speech-to-Text add-on for Twilio it makes me configure a callback url in the add-on configure tab. 
Now my issue is how do I get this to only affect ONE phone number? or a specific  TwiML? I cannot have all  going through the add-on.

Example:

phone number 1 ->  goes to some other webhook

phone number 2 -> uses TwiML bin with `<Record>` // I want this one to be transcribed by the IBM add-on

Should I rather have #2 hit a webhook which uses the IBM SDK and returns a record response? (if such a thing exists)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid Add-ons currently work on all your numbers on an account level right now. Can I suggest a work around that you start a subaccount and enable the Add-on for just the subaccount. Then move your number that you want to use for recording and transcribing to that subaccount.

Comment: Thanks, we figured that's what we would have to do.

Comment: hi @philnash sir, how are you, can you please tell me what CALLBACK URL to give when transcribe recording , please let me know

Comment: @JagveerSingh when the transcription is complete, Twilio will make an HTTP request to the callback URL with the results of the transcription. If you want to receive the transcription when it is complete, you should build an endpoint into your application that can receive this HTTP request.